# What is the best way to distribute an audio/video feed from a computer to TVs over existing indoor coax cable?

Tags: video, audio

We have existing coax cable in our office building and we'd like to put displays in our lobby and some other rooms in the office (where there are existing coax jacks).  We'd like these displays all controlled by a single PC.

What is the best way to accomplish the distribution aspect of this?  I have found ZeeVee's products and they seem like they will work, but I am wondering if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZeeVee's ZVBox solution is designed exactly for this - hotels, airports, companies etc use this. They can scale massively, they can take video or feeds from PC's and distribute one or both on different channels to existing HDTV's.

So what are you looking for that would be better?  It appears to cover all your bases.

Comment: It does cover all my bases, but if there is a lower cost option I may prefer that.  I recognize that ZeeVee's products are pretty low cost for what they provide, but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: I haven't seen any cheaper, and ZV is the solution I usually see in my clients. Sorry I can't help on costings.